# How to use the microphone but not the earphones from a four pole 3.5mm plug?

Tags: audio, microphone, sound-card

I recently got a new computer and I have CS:GO installed. Thing is, in order to play competitive you're basically required to have a microphone and I don't want to ask my parents because they just bought a £1000 computer. However, I have some old earphones which have a perfectly good microphone but I want to hear the sound through my speakers which are built in. My earphones only have one output wire. However when i plug it into the mic hole it nothing works but when i put it into the heaphones hole the speaker and mic work fine. If there is a way to change some settings which would fix this it will be appreciated
[The earphones look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfADi.jpg)

Comment: Open your sound mixer settings through the lower right hand speaker icon in your taskbar. It should enable you to select your output device. Alternatively rightclick that icon and check the playback device dialog. Supplying information on what sound card you have/motherboard (as it's most likely on-board) and what OS you're using would enable people do supply more concrete information.

Comment: _"when i put it into the heaphones hole the speaker and mic work fine"_ needs some rewriting....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PC's mic connector isn't supposed to handle your ["four-conductor TRRS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) headphones jack.

So what you need is a splitter what looks like this.

[image]

It wouldn't be so  expensive like a new mic. It will split the 4 segments jack up into two jacks: a simple mic (possibly stereo) and a stereo headphone (3 segments) one. You will need to connect the red one into your PC.

Comment: The standard 3 segment connector is TRS. Your headset connector is TRRS.

Comment: Also the connector where both things work might be a TRRS headset connector. I *half* suspect you can get what the OP wants in software

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a *headset* connector and a mic jack, which isn't that uncommon.

Now, if you have a *realtek* sound codec chip - which are pretty much the more common ones around you can click on the little cogwheel at the front, and set it *not* to mute the game audio when its plugged in  by unchecking the first box - this would let you use your headphones and speakers as once. The second option would let you set your speakers *independently* as a primary sound device.

[image]

YMMV with other drivers.